# Нужна ли тут запятая "Первое желания - это _ чтобы ...  (после это)?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли тут запятая "Первое желания - это _ чтобы ...  (после это)?

Comment: А все предложение лень написать? Ведь все зависит от продолжения предложения.

Answer (score 2):

После ЭТО нет знаков препинания. Например: «Первое желание – это чтобы экзамены скорее закончились».Можно считать, что  перед нами  аналог предложения «Первое желание – это окончание экзаменов» (сущ. И.п. – сущ. И.п.), тогда  наполнением  сказуемого  будет являться придаточное предложение.

Comment: Первое желание - это, чтобы отдохнуть, поехать в отпуск. Конечно, я бы по-другому построила предложение, но такое тоже возможно. Считаю, что, спрашивая о знаках препинания, предложение нужно писать полностью!